# How to do pattern matching for mutiline in perl

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

I am trying pattern matching on a line whose value argument is spread to multiple lines. My input file looks like

### input file content

```
config -type "cc" -opt "XX" -value { "A" \   
                                     "B" \
                                     "C" }\                                                                                                                                              -default "A" \
                    -text "\tA: XX size = 1/1\
\tB  : XX size = 1/10\
\tC : XX size = 1/100" -active dev

and the script to read the file is 

#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict();
use warnings();
use Cwd;

my $custom=$ARGV[0];
 ##pattern matching
open(my $fNew, "< $custom") or die "cannot open $!";
while(<$fNew>) {
  ##Pattern matching
  if( $_ =~ m/^\s*config\s+-type\s+([^\s+]+)\s+-opt\s+\"([^\"]+)\".*/gi ) {
   ##print the pattern
    print "$_\n";
  }
}
```

Output of the script:: config -type cc -opt "XX" -value { "A" \

I want my print command to return the entire config line instead of returning it till "A". Looks like the current pattern matching command ins not enough.

```
Please let me know if you have any questions.

Regards,
Divesh
```

Comment: The `m` flag can help you. Like this:`//m`. Read [more](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: i tried but it's not helpful and it captures only the first line                                                                   if ( $_ =~ m/^\s*-temp\s*\{(.+)\} /gi)

Comment: Where the loop, from which is `$_`? Post full snippet of code you tried. What do you want to get? An array of A, B, C, ...?

Comment: while(<$fNew>) { chomp $_; if ( $_ =~ m/^\s*-temp\s*\{(.+)\} /gi) { .....}                     and it returns only upto -temp {{"A"}

Comment: Note:`chomp` removes the `\n`

Comment: I removed that but it didn't help much and it's still printing the single line -temp {{"A"}

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code there. It's very hard to read in the comments. Also add a more complete example of input data. Are the `\n` in the data _literal_, or did you put them there to show that it's several lines?

Comment: By default, input is read line by line. Hence, at each iteration you end up applying the pattern match only onto a single line, not the whole text. See perldoc perlvar and look for `$/` (e.g. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$/ )

Answer (score 2):

I dont realize all possible combinations of data blocks in your input file and its format. If I misunderstood, tell me.

Consider you file has such **format**:

```
someblock1 -option1 value -option2 value
someblock2 -option1 value -option2 value
...
config -option1 value -option2 value
...
someblockN -option1 value -option2 value
```

You want to get all `config`-block to scalar variable using multiline pattern. Since this block could contain newline characters.

---

Here's some code, that does such task without loops:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open  my $fh, '<file' or die "$!\n"; my $file = join '', <$fh>; close $fh;
$file =~ /config.*?-value\s?\{.*?"(\w)"\s*\}.*?\1\s?:.*?(?:\n|$)/s;
print $&;
```

This pattern will match as many descriptions like `D : XX size = 1/100" -active dev` as pointed in `-value{...}` option. (Of course, if you follow some order when generating the file)

Comment: Thanks redOct. I can make it a variable instead of an array.

Comment: Actually line starts with some other pattern and -temp is in the middle of the line so putting into an array won't be useful here.                                                  ABC::CDE -show 1 -type choices -default "A" -value {{"A"} \n {"B}"\n {"C"}} -hidden 0

Comment: @Divesh Rastogi You should specify what type of input could appear and what do you expect to retrieve. Edit your question please

Comment: Here you go ....   ABC::CDE -show 1 -type choices -default "A" -value {{"A"}\n 
          {"B}"\n 
           {"C"}} -text "Nail It" -hidden 0

Answer (score 0):

Below RegExp command should match

> /^\s*-temp[\s* {}\"[a-z]+]*/gim

use online regexp coach to test it

http://regexr.com/v1/